# It's a federal crime to pay someone to do your kid's homework?

Tags: united-states

I read a news article today that announced that [a mother who paid a third party to take classes in lieu of her son got sentenced to prison](https://www.boston.com/news/education/2020/07/15/mom-gets-5-weeks-in-prison-for-sons-online-class-cheating). I assume this is a federal case because in previous news reports about the same investigation, it was described as an FBI project.

The story, however, does not say what the mother was charged with. What exactly was the crime for which she is going to prison? The ubiquitous "wire fraud"?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as history. Politics or Law seem better fits. And according to Bloomberg: Yes, the charge was *wire fraud*.

Comment: The article linked to in the question states that she pleaded guilty to a count of conspiracy to commit wire fraud.

Comment: It is probably worth noting (as the article does) that this case comes out of *Operation Varsity Blues,* the joint FBI/US Atty for Massachusetts investigation that led to the recent college admissions bribery scandal. Some of those cases relied on wire fraud as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What laws did Lori Loughlin (and friends) break?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/what-laws-did-lori-loughlin-and-friends-break)

Answer (score 5):

The article actually does say what she was charged with:

> The Newport Beach, California, woman pleaded guilty in January to a count of **conspiracy to commit wire fraud**.

Searching for "US v Littlefair" quickly turned up a [DoJ site](https://www.justice.gov/usao-ma/investigations-college-admissions-and-testing-bribery-scheme) with a link to the relevant [plea agreement and charging document](https://www.justice.gov/usao-ma/page/file/1224566/download).  This confirms that the charge was that Littlefair

> conspired [...] to commit wire fraud [...] in violation of Title 18, United States Code, Section 1343.  All in violation of Title 18, United States Code, Section 1349.

[18 USC 1343](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1343) is the general wire fraud statute, and [18 USC 1349](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1349) covers conspiracies.